# Nested Projections

Tags: spring, jpa, nested, spring-data

I'm using Spring Data 1.13 and spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.5.4.  (can't upgrade)

I need to fetch only few fields in nested entities and i have a multiple optional search criteria...

```
public class Entity1 {
   private Entity2 e2; --> i need e2.innerEntity.field
   private Entity3 e3; --> i need e3.innerEntity2.field... 
.... other entity and fields...
}
```

fetching 950 Entity1 is a very slow  task due to Eager Fetching on nested entity...

I've tried with Specification, but I can't do projection (or I am not able...)

what can i do? :( thanks for your attention... and i'm sorry for my English.